# ImageStream metadata.name problem when deploy app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, openshift

I have microservice on ASP.NET Core 2.2.
Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DBPatchDeployService/DBPatchDeployService.csproj", "DBPatchDeployService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DBPatchDeployService/DBPatchDeployService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DBPatchDeployService"
RUN dotnet build "DBPatchDeployService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DBPatchDeployService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DBPatchDeployService.dll"]
```

This dockerfile was generated by VS 2019. Its works well on local docker. But when I try to make OpenShift app

```
oc new-app . --strategy=docker --source-secret=gitlab --name=lk-db-patch-service
```

I get errors:

```
 error: ImageStream "core/aspnet" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "core/aspnet": may not contain '/'
```

Whats wrong with it? Or how to avoid it?

Comment: I think the default in OpenShift is to look at the internal registry first...in which case, that URL doesn't conform to how the internal registry is configured. I know there's a way to tell OpenShift to use external registries, I just don't know off hand and I'm on mobile right now. Hopefully that can point you in the right direction?

Comment: May be, I have limited rights on server, so I will conect with admins later. Thanks for some help =)